# Scroll to bottom of div event (overflow)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi please help me with my fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gWD66/2663/)

I have this div

```
<div id='divdiv' style="height: 200px; overflow:scroll">
<span id='content'> 
  Scroll down!Scroll down!
  Scroll down!Scroll down!
  Scroll down!Scroll down!
  Scroll down!Scroll down!
  Scroll down!Scroll down!
  Scroll down!Scroll down!
</span>
    <i id="selectedElement">s</i>

</div>
```

this div has overflow and I have scroll event that trigger when `<i id="selectedElement">s</i>` is visible in div

```
 //function to check if target element is visible
    function isElementVisible(elementToBeChecked)
    {
        var TopView = $('#divdiv').scrollTop();
        var BotView = TopView + $('#divdiv').height();
        var TopElement = $(elementToBeChecked).offset().top;
        var BotElement = TopElement + $(elementToBeChecked).height();
        return ((BotElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
    }


//scroll event
$('#divdiv').scroll(function () {
       isOnView = isElementVisible("#selectedElement");
       if(isOnView){
           $('#content').append('<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a');

       }else{ // If not visible

       }
});
```

if the `<i id="selectedElement">s</i>` is visible i added some value `'<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a'` just to test if i reach the bottom but I can't make it work.

it should function as

when the target element is visible i will load some content then user will scroll again to bottom and when the target element is "again" visible i will load some more content again

Comment: What exactly should it be doing?

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz when the target element is visible i will load some content then user will scroll again to bottom and when the target element is "again" visible i will load some more content again

Comment: The div size is just enough to include whatever you have printed.

Comment: @Hariprasad the thing is, the content is response from server if i load let say 10 thousand records as one response to one request it is heavy and slow to load so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gWD66/2667/).
This appends a random number to the 'content' div as soon as it reaches the bottom.

```
function appendContent()
{
    if ($('#divdiv')[0].scrollHeight <= $('#divdiv')[0].scrollTop + $('#divdiv').height() ) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

$('#divdiv').scroll(function () {
   if(appendContent()){
       $('#content').append('<br>' + Math.random());
   }else{ // If not visible

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/gWD66/2664/)**

Use this

```
 $('#divdiv').scrollTop($('#divdiv').prop("scrollHeight"));
```

OR

```
$('#divdiv').scrollTop($('#divdiv')[0].scrollHeight);
```

**[scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)** scrolls the div to the bottom.

**[prop("scrollHeight")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight)** gives your the actual height, and not default display height - `height()`.

Comment: a good progress thanks, but when i scrolled up another content is loaded

Comment: What content is loaded? I don't find anything.

Comment: this one `<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a` acts like content that has been loaded. thanks

Comment: See, the scroll function would work only if `isElementVisible("#selectedElement");`, according to your code. This is the reason why you can't scroll to bottom if `<i>` is not visible.